# PowerShell: How to check local accounts are Enabled/Active

Tags: windows, powershell

I found this code [here](https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_get_local_group_membership_report.html), and altered it to my needs.
However one thing I need to add to the csv output is to indicate if the Local account is Enabled (or Active) or not. It would be nice to get it for the domain accounts as well, but the real need is for the Local machine accounts.

```
$strComputer = "domain-computer01.mydomain.com", "domain-computer02" 
$result = @()
foreach ($instance in $strcomputer)
{
    #Remove Domain from Hostname if it is used in $strComputer
    $instance_no_Domain = ($instance -replace ('(^[\w-_\d]+)\.(.*)', '$1'))
    Write-Host "Computer: $instance"
    $computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$instance"
$objCount = ($computer.psbase.children | measure-object).count
    Write-Host "Q-ty objects for computer '$computer' = $objCount"
$Counter = 1
foreach ($adsiObj in $computer.psbase.children) {
    switch -regex($adsiObj.psbase.SchemaClassName) {
        "group" {
            $group = $adsiObj.name
            $LocalGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$instance/$group,group"
            $Members = @($LocalGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
            $objCount = ($Members | measure-object).count
            Write-Host "Q-ty objects for group '$group' = $objCount"
            $GName = $group.tostring()

            ForEach ($Member In $Members) {
                $Name = $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null)
                $Path = $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("ADsPath", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null)
                #$active =  $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Enabled", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null)
                Write-Host " Object = $Path"
                    
                $isGroup = ($Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Class", "GetProperty", $Null, $Member, $Null) -eq "group")
                    If (($Path -like "*/$instance/*") -or ($Path -like "*/$instance_no_Domain/*") -Or ($Path -like "WinNT://NT*")) {
                    $Type = "Local"
                }
                Else { $Type = "Domain" }
                $result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Computername   = $instance_no_Domain
                    NameMember     = $Name
                    PathMember     = $Path
                    TypeMember    = $Type
                    ParentGroup    = $GName
                    isGroupMember = $isGroup
                #   IsActive    = $active
                    Depth          = $Counter
                }
            }
        }
    } #end switch
} #end foreach
} #end foreach instance
Write-Host "Total objects = " ($result | measure-object).count
$result = $result | select-object Computername, ParentGroup, NameMember, TypeMember, PathMember, isGroupMember, Depth #, IsActive
$result | Export-Csv -path ("C:\temp\LocalGroups({0})-{1:yyyyMMddHHmm}.csv" -f
    "list-of-accounts", (Get-Date)) -Delimiter "," -Encoding "UTF8" -force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That script is quite dated. Do you need to support powershell 2?

Comment: @Doug Maurer  No, it doesn't have to be PowerShell v2, It was what i had initially found online that worked and then altered it to my needs.  It seems to work in PowerShell v.7.1 but if there is newer ways that are more efficient and quicker, and can be run remotely on servers that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option in PowerShell version 5.1 is to use `Get-LocalUser`

```
$user = Get-LocalUser -Name Administrator
$user.Enabled
```

You can also use `Get-WmiObject` or the newer version since PowerShell version 3 `Get-CimInstance`.

```
$user = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName <Server>
$user.Disabled
```

Comment: I cant seem to get Get-LocalUser to run remotely, It throws errors of
`User MDorry was not found.`
And that user is a Local user on the server it running against, not a Domain user. I do not see a way to pass the server to the cmdlet to tell it to run on that server.  It seems to be looking on my local laptop for that name.

Comment: So I tried InvokeCommand to run the Get-Localuser cmdlet to run on the remote machine, and the cmdlet is not recognized on that server, it has version 3 of PowerShell.  I cant upgrade Powershell, dont have permissions to do so.

Comment: @Rugbyball , try `Get-CimInstance`. That should also work. Alternatively, you can try `Get-WmiObject`.